# Finding the JPA provider used

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a project have below parent

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

and  have below dependency.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

For any crud operation we are using MongoDBReppository interface My question

> 1) Is who is implementing this interface ? of course any jpa provider
>   is providing the feature, but
>
> 2) Which JPA provider is used with below dependency?

I tried checking dependency in my intellij list but didn't find my answer.

Comment: Mongodbrepository is spring data mongodb. It is not jpa! There is no jpa provider. It uses mongodb api!

Comment: What is your question exactly ? You can check implementation for `MongoRepository` which is `SimpleMongoRepositry` in spring-data-mongodb dependency and spring-data-mongodb dependency has mongodb-java-driver dependency which is used to perform CRUD on mongo database.